# Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{2x^2-1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

The standard integral for the function $\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}$ is
$$=\frac{1}{2a} \log (\frac{x-a}{x+a})$$

So the integral for this should be $$\frac{1}{2} \log (\frac{\sqrt 2 x-1}{\sqrt 2x+1})$$

But according to the calculator, the right answer is
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2} \log (\frac{\sqrt 2x-1}{\sqrt 2x+1})$$

Why is my answer wrong?

Comment: $a = \sqrt{2}$ so you're missing a radical in the denominator out front.

Comment: You solved the integral by substitution and forgot to account for scaling ${\rm d}x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $t=x\sqrt{2}$ then your integral follows the standard form of the integral:
$$\int \frac{dx}{2x^2-1} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int \frac{dt}{t^2-1} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \log \left(\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right)+\mathrm{C}= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \log \left(\frac{x\sqrt{2}-1}{x\sqrt{2}+1}\right)+\mathrm{C}$$
So, the $\sqrt{2}$ comes from the substitution.

Comment: Does this answer "Why is my answer wrong?"

Answer (score 3):

$$\int\dfrac1{2x^2-1}dx=\frac12\int\dfrac1{x^2-\dfrac12}dx$$

$$=\dfrac1{2\sqrt2}\log\dfrac{x-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}}{x+\dfrac1{\sqrt2}}$$

$$=\dfrac1{2\sqrt2}\log\dfrac{\sqrt2x-1}{\sqrt2x+1}$$

with $a=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $F'(x)=f(x)$ and if $a\ne0$, then $F'(ax)=af'(ax)$. So, a primitive of $f$ is $\frac1aF$. In your case, $a=\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $z = \sqrt{2} \, x$  and ${\rm d}z = \sqrt{2}\, {\rm d}x$ into $$ \int \frac{1}{z^2-1} {\rm d}z = \frac{1}{2} \ln \left( \frac{z-1}{z+1} \right)$$

to get

$$ \sqrt{2} \int \frac{1}{2 x^2-1} {\rm d}x = \frac{1}{2} \ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}x-1}{\sqrt{2}x+1} \right) $$

and move the $\sqrt{2}$ on the other side.

Comment: @NancyRutkowskie a sour dino? or a dinosaur?

Comment: Never mind! all is good. sounds the same! :)

Answer (score 1):

The integral matches the given formula if you write

$$\int\frac{dx}{2x^2-1}=\frac12\int\frac{dx}{x^2-(\frac1{\sqrt2})^2}.$$

Then

$$I=\frac1{2\cdot2\cdot\frac1{\sqrt2}}\log\frac{x-\frac1{\sqrt2}}{x+\frac1{\sqrt2}}=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\log\frac{\sqrt2x-1}{\sqrt2x+1}.$$

You did not apply the formula correctly.